# How to set "feature-state" value in mapbox js combined with paint "circle-color" property

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I have some circles whose color is decided by real-time data. When the data changes the color will be updated. So want to use "map.setPaintProperty" function to achieve this.
Checked the API "feature-state" property may be for dynamic renderer but not know how to combined it with "case" condition expression.
The core logic snippet is as below, expect tValue<16, set "feature-state" with "low", tValue>16 and <18,  "feature-state" with "middle" and so on.
The code pen link is :[time slider example](https://codepen.io/gisfinder/pen/JjwxNzN?editors=1010)

```
 map.addLayer({
          "id": "points" + i,
            "type": "circle",
            "paint": {
            "circle-radius": 8,
             "circle-color":
            /*********** where to put "feat-state" expression **********/
              [
                'case',
                ['<', tValue, 16],
             
                "rgba(70,77,152,1)",
                ['<', tValue, 18],
             
                "rgba(195, 226, 222 ,1)",
                ['<', tValue, 20],
              
                "rgba(120, 204, 32,1)",
                ['<', tValue, 22],
              
                "rgba(255,99,71,1)",
            
                "rgba(220,20,60,1)"
                 
              ]
              }
              })
```

Comment: If you want to use feature state I think you need to add a promote ID or generate ID on the GeoJSON source to start with.